# Is it possible for a JMS topic to have multiple publishers?

Tags: jms

From what I've read so-far, a JMS Topic is 1-to-Many and I wonder if its possible to support Many-to-Many using a topic. Consider a topic called "Reports" with multiple services spread out across an enterprise needing to publish scheduled reports. Having multiple publishers would alleviate the need to subscribe interested applications to a topic for each of the reporting services.

Comment: Yep - absolutely.  Just make multiple MessageProducers and publish away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create many `TopicPublisher` from your `TopicSession`, and many applications can connect the same `Topic` using `TopicPublisher` or `TopicSubscriber`.

Answer (score 4):

@Mondain: yes, very much possible. A practical example would be live stock market price feed provided by multiple sources and those feed consumed by multiple channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, and call `CreateMessageProducer` to create a new instance of producer anywhere in your application.

```
  public ActiveMqProducer(string activeMqServiceUrl)
  {  
        _activeMqServiceUrl = activeMqServiceUrl; 

        IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(new Uri(_activeMqServiceUrl));

        _activeMqConnection = factory.CreateConnection();

        _activeMqSession = _activeMqConnection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.Transactional);

        _activeMqConnection.Start();
  }

  private IMessageProducer CreateMessageProducer(string mqTopicName)
  {
        ITopic destination = SessionUtil.GetTopic(_activeMqSession, mqTopicName);
        var producer = _activeMqSession.CreateProducer(destination);
        return producer;
  }
```